# Queria a ajuda de como criar um link público do meu perfil com php (meusite.com/usuario) como no linkedin e instagram

Tags: php

Um link similar ao do linkedin com url personalizada com o nome do usuario (meusite.com/usuario), ele seria visível para todos e o usuário poderia compartilhar esse link com qualquer pessoa. Tenho criado o perfil e as informações do usuário mas não estou sabendo como criar esse link personalizado.

Answer (score 1):

Para criação de Urls personalizadas / amigáveis, você vai precisar utilizar algum sistema de rotas no seu projeto. Basicamente é uma um lugar aonde você especifíca as Urls que seu site/api possui e qual arquivo será executado quando cada url for acessada.

Se você estiver utilizando algum framework web, provavelmente ele já tenha algo tipo integrado e que você possa utilizar. Caso esteja fazendo tudo usando só PHP, Html, etc... você pode procurar por alguma classe pronta para PHP que te ajude nisso, vou deixar uma de exemplo abaixo, mas recomendo dar uma olhada em outras e para ver qual te atende melhor:

https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router

Você também criar seu próprio esquema de rotas ou urls utilizando/configurando o .htaccess para fazer o redirecinamento das urls para os scripts correspondentes, mas pode ser que acabe dando mais trabalho. Vou deixar aqui um tutorial sobre como criar o seu próprio:

https://alexandrebbarbosa.wordpress.com/2019/04/17/phpconstruir-um-sistema-de-rotas-para-mvc-primeira-parte/

Se tiver a opção de utilizar algum framework no projeto, recomendo fortemente, pois ele provavelmente já terá toda essa parte de rotas e muitas outras funcionalidades prontas e bem organizadas. Se não quiser sair do PHP, o [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) é uma excelente opção.